# Startup making me pay legal costs of my vested options, is that legal?

Tags: contract-law

A startup I worked for had promised me to grant my options that were vested, however, they are making me pay the legal costs of executing those options. Is that legal? On the contract, it says nothing about legal costs. I feel like I'm being hold for ransom with the fees.

Comment: It is certainly crappy and given that a vested option is a long term investment I'd quit working for a place like that.

Comment: Can you enumerate what they are assessing as "the legal costs of executing those options?"  Do you perhaps mean some tax cost to the company?

Comment: Around 650$ in usd what do you think?

Comment: $650 for what? Exercising an option means paying A x B for A shares at strike price B for A shares of stock at the current price. There should be no lawyer needed. When you got the options, what documents did you get? Were any others incorporated by reference? Did any of these mention a fee at exercise?